# Элемент для изменения масштаба страницы

Tags: javascript, css, масштабирование

Приветствую. Подскажите, с помощью каких инструментов можно соорудить данный элемент сайта. Нужно что бы при его использовании менялся масштаб страницы. Может существуют какие нибудь подобные шаблоны, требующие только стилизации?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте трансформацию [**`transform: scale();`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale):

```js
document.querySelector('#changeScale').addEventListener('click', _ => {
  document.body.style.transform = 'scale(2)';
});
```

```css
body{
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div>Текст</div>
<input type='button' id='changeScale' value='Изменить масштаб' />
```